# Alexa for Business

Tags: amazon-echo

I'm interested in Alexa for Business, and I'm wondering if the Drop-In feature that is present in the Regular Alexa implementation is available in the business implementation? I have not been able to find any Amazon Documents referencing this feature, does anyone know any details about this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it wouldn't be implemented.  You're still using the same basic Alexa app, with the same basic features, simply with adaptations to make it more business friendly, and with added layers of security.

I also found a few people who mention the ability of using the drop in feature on Alexa for business.  For example, shortly after the debut of Alexa for business, [theinquirer.net](https://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/3022217/amazon-alexa-business-launches) ran an article in which they mention the following:

> Alexa for Business would make teleconferencing that bit easier - it just needs to expand on at the existing "drop-in" function of the Echo.

...suggesting that the feature is implemented, but that the inquirer felt that businesses could use some little touch ups to make it even better.

I also found [this article](https://www.stratospherenetworks.com/blog/3-ways-alexa-business-transformed-workday/) in which the author states that drop in is one of the features of Alexa for business which transformed their workday.  The author writes,

> **3. Making it easier to drop in.** I can give Alexa voice commands to call/drop in on others in the office to collaborate and communicate, which saves even more time. Picking up your cell phone requires an extra hand!

Do remember that [not all devices are compatible with Drop In](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=202153130).  Currently, the Amazon Tap and the Echo Look are not compatible, and the Echo Auto, the Echo Input, and mobile devices using the app can only initiate Drop-In, they cannot receive Drop-in calls.

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful, I agree with you that I don't see why it wouldn't be implemented, however from what I can tell, Alexa for Business's documentation does not mention the feature, so I was a bit unsure and looking for another opinion.

Answer (score -1):

It's not supported. Also those articles in the other answer are not indicative of it being supported.

EDIT:

You won't find it in the docs. I tried to find the email thread between our AWS rep and our business that detailed why it is not supported in Alexa For Business, but it's since been archived and I don't have access to it. You can use your Alexa device for meetings, but you are not able to use the drop in feature.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer!  It would be great if you could back this up with citations / explain how you came to the conclusion that it's not supported.  Otherwise, this is really more of a comment than an answer.  It would be best if you could [edit] accordingly.  Thank you!